# Char array in C overwritten with strncat()?

Tags: c, arrays, concatenation, overwrite, strcat

This is so weird. It seems that depending on which char array I declare/initialize first, a blank array is overwritten when I'm doing strncat() on the other array in C.
code:

```
    char t_str[]="";
    char ran_str[]="";
    ... inbuf ="8889  ";
    while (inbuf[pos]!=' ')
    {
       strncat(t_str, &inbuf[pos],1);
       printf("t_str so far: %s\n", t_str);
       printf("ran_str so far: %s\n", ran_str);
       pos++;
    }
```

Output:

```
   t_str so far: 8
   ran_str so far:
   t_str so far: 88
   ran_str so far: 8
   t_str so far: 888
   ran_str so far: 88
   t_str so far: 8889
   ran_str so far: 889
```

If I initialize `ran_str` before `t_str`, then  `ran_str[]` is not filled up as I'm `strncat()` `t_str`. Any reason why this might be happening?

Comment: You're concat'ing data into an array exactly **one** char wide, and walking straight into the land of **undefined behavior** in doing so.

Comment: So if it be safer to give a size to the arrays when I initialize them like str[bufsize]=""?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of several problems:

1. `t_str` (and `ran_str`) are only 1 byte long. (The null-terminator)
2. There is no space in `inbuf` so the loop never ends.

Because `ran_str` is declared right after `t_str` it comes right after it in memory, so when `strncat` overflows the `t_str` buffer it writes into `ran_str`.

You need to allocate more memory for `t_str` (and probably `ran_str`) and check you're not overflowing them. You also need to make sure you don't read past the end of `inbuf`, by checking if you haven't reached the null-terminator.

Comment: I meant to add some wspaces in inbuf after the last number

Comment: Oh i see, will this be a problem in Java?

Comment: @jerryh91 it's still a good idea to check if you haven't reached the null-terminator yet, if only as good practice.

Comment: @jerryh91 It won't be a problem in Java because the JVM does memory management for you.

Comment: It won't be a problem in Java because it will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException when you try to overrun your array.

Answer (score 1):

Culprit is your code which defines arrays:

```
char t_str[]="";
char ran_str[]="";
```

you should provide a length to both arrays. In above case I think `t_str` and `ran_str` both would get adjacent addresses. You can try this to confirm:

```
printf("%p %p\n", t_str, ran_str);
```

Fix it by using some length of array:

```
char t_str[10]="";
char ran_str[10]="";
```

Comment: I meant to add some wspaces in inbuf after the last number

Comment: wspaces? I didn't get you. Can you please explain?

Comment: wspaces == white spaces

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
char t_str[] = "";
```

the array contains only 1 character, just enough room for the trailing null byte. When you then do:

```
strncat(t_str, &inbuf[pos], 1);
```

it copies one character into `t_str` (overwriting the null) and then *appends* a null byte to it. That means it's writing outside the bounds of the array, which is undefined behavior. In your implementation, it appears to be overwriting the beginning of `ran_str`.

The third argument to `strncat` should always be 1 less than the room remaining in the target array, to allow room for the null that will be appended. So it should be:

```
strncat(t_str, &inbuf[pos], sizeof(t_str)-strlen(t_str)-1);
```